# Click html submit form button from java http POST

Tags: java, android, http-post, form-submit

I'm tying to build an app which will send SMS over websites you can use to send SMS free.

Website has 2 input fields and a button to send SMS.

```
<form method="POST" action="db.php">

        <input type="text" class="span8" name="numberOfRecipient" required=""><br> 

        <textarea class="span8" name="message" id="mes" maxlength="145" onkeydown="textCounter(this); required=""></textarea>

        <p><button class="btn-main" type="submit" id="send">SendSMS</button></p>

</form>
```

This is my code:

```
public class Glavna extends Activity{

    TextView httpStuff;
    String brija;

    HttpClient client;
    HttpPost request;
    HttpResponse response;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        try {
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            request = new HttpPost("https://www.sendfreeSMS.com");

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("numberOfRecipient", "214555896"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", "Some kind of message"));

            request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            response = client.execute(request);

            // Get the response
            BufferedReader rd;
            rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 


}
}
```

when i execute this code i get only the html code of the page and message is not send. I'm new to android but i think i need to get the the html code of the next page that sais message send successfully...

can someone tell me how to click this submit button?

Answer (score 0):

Are you pointing to your php script?
    request = new HttpPost("https://www.sendfreeSMS.com/yourscript.php");

Comment: no, should i point to php?   This is not my site, and i found that there is db.php that site redirects to when you click on send sms but when you go to https://www.sendfreeSMS.com/db.php it shows you that sending sms failed so i guess that php is just notification weather sending failed or was successful...